# python pandas selecting with loc through boolean expression

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, expression

is it possible to do boolean expression with multiple rows?

Objective is for the "GROUPER" column, it will find the specify row value, then for those 2 rows it will change the value of the rows in column "Risk" to "difficult". Maybe im not suppose to use "and"? Thanks!

```
GROUPER     RISK
80906373    N/A
85920225    N/A
85920226    N/A
85920250    Difficult
80958231    Difficult

df.loc[df['GROUPER'] == 80906010 and 80906220,['Risk']] = 
'Difficult'
```

Comment: I don't understand how that condition can ever be `True`, even if the syntax was correct? (It will be True but not for a good reason, so I'm trying to work out what logic you're trying to apply)

Comment: The deleted comment suggested `isin()` and I think that was probably what you wanted but I can't be sure. You want to test whether `df['GROUPER']` is equal to 80906010 _OR_ `df['GROUPER']` equal to 80906220?

Comment: Can you show a sample dataframe and a desired output?

Comment: I would like for example, the rest of the Risk to become Difficult. To do that I would like to pick specific rows, and multiple of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter and assign to the wanted column using the `loc` method like this:

```
df.loc[df['GROUPER'].isin([80906010, 80906220]),'Risk'] = 'Difficult'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the @moshevi answer is **PERFECT**.
I Think that the same syntax using two lines is clearly.

```py
df.loc[df['GROUPER'].isin([80906010, 80906220]),
                                        'Risk'] = 'Difficult'
```

This way:

```py
df.loc[ anything_true ,
          'your_column'] = something
```

**If anyway this answer should be removed, please let me know.**